# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android

I get this crash report a lot of time from fabric.io. But my tests not get any crash at my phone so i dont exactly to find solution this error.

Shortly i pick image from gallery and than user crop this image and set this file resource to imageview.

And also i use this crop image library. 
https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

**i call from there**

```
 profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(MediaStoreUtils.getPickImageIntent(MainActivity.this), REQUEST_PICTURE);
        }

    });
```

---

```
public static Intent getPickImageIntent(final Context context) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select picture");
}
```

**onCreate**

```
File Folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/");
    croppedImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/test.jpg");
    if (!Folder.exists()) {
        Folder.mkdirs();
        File noMedia = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder" + "/.nomedia");
        try {
            noMedia.createNewFile();
            croppedImageFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

**onActivityResult**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);


    if ((requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        Uri croppedImage = Uri.fromFile(croppedImageFile);
        CropImageIntentBuilder cropImage = new CropImageIntentBuilder(200, 200, croppedImage);
        cropImage.setOutlineColor(0xFF03A9F4);
        cropImage.setSourceImage(imageReturnedIntent.getData());

        startActivityForResult(cropImage.getIntent(this), REQUEST_CROP_PICTURE);
    } else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CROP_PICTURE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

        profileImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(croppedImageFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        profileImage.setTag(Constants.IMAGE_IS_DEFINED);
    }
```

---

**Crash report**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=file:///storage/sdcard0/folder/test.jpg (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3209)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3252)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.app.MainActivity.onActivityResult()
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5387)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3252)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at          com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: can you share the code where you put the extras into the intent? It seems like you doesn't set the result code properly (`ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=file:///storage/sdcard0/folder/test.jpg (has extras) }}`) see result=-1

Comment: i update my question and shere it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you doesn't set the result code properly:

```
ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=file:///storage/sdcard0/folder/test.jpg (has extras) }}
```

`result=-1` usually means error, so you're probably having an error wherever you call the `Intent`.

Maybe you're not setting the best way the result. You have to do it like this:
`setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, yourData);`

`who=null` also seems like the `Activity` which is sending back the result is `null`, but it really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I think maybe user cancel pick image and it cause intent return null  ?

 if ((requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) 

I add this statement && imageReturnedIntent!=null. Is it reasonable ?